# Check first data acf field available from tomorrow

Tags: php, wordpress

I need to display the first data acf field available from tomorrow.

For example:

I have 5 post with this data: 18/02, 20/02, 21/02, 25/02, 27/02, 28/02

Today: 18/02 => I need to display post with data 20/02 (> of today but first available)

Tomorrow: 19/02 => I need to display post with data 20/02 (> of tomowwor but first available)

20/02 => I need to display post with data 21/02 (> of data but first available)

I have this loop but I don't understand where I can insert this condition and how:

```
<?php   
$today = date('Ymd'); // Today's date
$data = get_field(data_post_available);

$args = array(
    'category_name' => 'post_available',
    'orderby' => 'date',
    'order'   => 'ASC',
    'meta_key' => 'data_post_available',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
    'offset' => 1
);
?>
<?php if( $the_query->have_posts() ): ?>
    <?php while( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>    

       <?php the_title(); ?>

    <?php endwhile; ?>
 <?php endif; ?>
```

Can you help me?

Comment: Is it an answer to your question? https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/156473/193435

Comment: No because here you display all post into 1 mouth and not next available